# why the images orientation is changing when loading the image from the cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which i am loading the images from the image caches.`

```
if(![[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:imagepath])

                {   cell.bannerview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_imags.png"];
                    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.bannerview2,imagepath,@"no_imags.png",[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],nil];
                    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate  *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                    [appDelegate performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateImageViewInBackground:) withObject:myArray];   

                }
                else 
                {
                    cell.bannerview2.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:imagepath];
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                cell.bannerview2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_imags.png"];  

            }
```

this is how i am doing the image cache process.But the problem is when the image is larger than the required frame the image orientation is changing.this is my image updating code in the appdelegate

```
-(void)updateImageViewInBackground:(NSArray *)idsArray{
    //NSLog(@"IN METHOD idsArray %@",idsArray);
    NSString *iconurl = (NSString *)[idsArray objectAtIndex:1];

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if([[ImageCache sharedImageCache] hasImageWithKey:iconurl]){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageViewInForeground:) withObject:idsArray waitUntilDone:NO];
        [pool release];
        return;
    }
    if([iconurl length] > 0){
        [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] saveImageToCacheOfUrl:iconurl];
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageViewInForeground:) withObject:idsArray waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];
}
-(void)updateImageViewInForeground:(NSArray *)idsArray{

    UIImageView *weatherView = (UIImageView *)[idsArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *iconurl = (NSString *)[idsArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    weatherView.image = [[ImageCache sharedImageCache] getImagefromCacheOrUrl:iconurl];
    if(weatherView.image == nil){
        NSString *defaultname = (NSString *)[idsArray objectAtIndex:2];
        weatherView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: defaultname];
    }
    BOOL resizeImgView = [(NSNumber *)[idsArray objectAtIndex:3] boolValue];
    if(resizeImgView){
        //NSLog(@"resizeImgView %@ %@",iconurl,weatherView);
        weatherView.frame = CGRectMake(weatherView.frame.origin.x, weatherView.frame.origin.y, weatherView.image.size.width, weatherView.image.size.height);





    }
    [pool release];
}
```

can anybody help me?